# Select All Checkbox slow on chrome (Databinding with Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have some script in controller which would bind a selection of checkbox and let me select all the checkboxes (Around 1000).. Unfortunately the rendering of selections is significantly slower in Chrome compared to firefox and safari which are doing fine. The Javascript I wrote is fine as logging the time between start and end of the calls give me a gap of just a few millisecs.

So if you notice in the script below, I'm populating and making the data available for field.selectedFilters.
As mentioned earlier, the JS execution is fine and it all boils down to the rendering that browser is doing. I have read multiple posts but none of them address with the binding involved. Most of them talk about accessing DOM directly. Any thoughts would be appreciated

HTML

```
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               checklist-model="field.selectedFilters"
                               checklist-value="data">
                        {{::data.label}}
                    </label>


 <div class="selectAllCheckBox" ng-controller="checkBoxController">
        <b>
            <input type="checkbox" data-ng-click="checkAll(scopeValue(field.id))"
                   ng-model="selectedAll"/>
            Check All
        </b>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
app.controller("checkBoxController", function ($scope) {

$scope.checkAll = function (items) {

   $scope.field.selectedFilters=[]; // Initializing the scope variable
    $scope.Items = items;

    if ($scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.selectedAll= true;
        $scope.field.selectedFilters = angular.copy($scope.Items);

    }
    else {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
        $scope.field.selectedFilters = [];
        // Unchecking would empty the above scope variable
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: why are you copying selectedFilters? angular.copy() is pretty slow

Comment: @Ronnie: selectedFilters is part of preexisting code which I'm editing at the moment to accomodate check all feature which is why I'm copying Items into selectedfilter to be used. But as mentioned logging the time before and after angular.copy() shows me that it's taking few milliseconds. So I assume that isn't the problem. It's basically rendering the selection of checkboxes in the view that seems to be a question (Again Safari and Firefox are just fine) It's all with chrome